# Android Firebase: How to get the key of a different User ID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the different user ID stored under the current user ID. I'm not sure how to get the actual key which has a random user ID. See Firebase structure.

[image]

so how do I get the actual key which is a random User ID?

See code so far:

```
public void getAgencyAdminID(final String nodeName){
    database.child("sand")
            .child(nodeName)
            .child("agencyAdmin")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
            });
}
```

I appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `sand` node is a direct child of your Firebase database and `nodeName` points to `ert` and the `userID` is `rC6eW88yy3hhswdBrCT9cmd6rJB2`, to get that key, please use the following code:

```
public void getAgencyAdminID(final String nodeName){
    database.child("sand")
        .child(nodeName)
        .child(userID)
        .child("agencyAdmin")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = child.getKey();
                Log("TAG", key);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
}
```

The reason you need the loop: when you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results.
So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: Great! Worked! Thanks!

Comment: The only difference from my answer was `child(userID)` which wasn't in the original question. Miki edited this into my answer so now both answers are the same. But where did `child(userID)` come from?

Comment: @Grimthorr As we can see in OP's screenshot, there is an id `rC6eW88yy3hhswdBrCT9cmd6rJB2` which can be only the userID. So this child is also needed when creating the reference.

Comment: @AlexMamo I see, I just assumed the `rC6eW88yy3hhswdBrCT9cmd6rJB2` node was handled by the `nodeName` variable and `sand` was interchangeable (or a typo) for `ert`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know the location of this value, so your current code is almost there. You'll just need to iterate over the children of the returned `DataSnapshot` and grab the key for each using [`DataSnapshot#getKey()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getKey()):

```
public void getAgencyAdminID(final String nodeName){
    database.child("sand")
            .child(nodeName)
            .child(userID)
            .child("agencyAdmin")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(child.getKey());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
            });
}
```

You need to use the `for` iteration loop on [`DataSnapshot#getChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getChildren()) here because the returned `DataSnapshot` holds all children at the `agencyAdmin` node.

Comment: hey Grimthorr, thanks again. I tried but it returns "agencyAdmin" as a key.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my [ninja-edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info) in the grace period: you'll need to iterate over the children of the `dataSnapshot` using a `for` loop on `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`.